# Ordering data in the table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have three tables created by uploaded data from the previous file. I would like to insert data in defined places, so that each service is a separate record in the table and has a separate quantity and amount assigned.
My php function:

```
function listService()
{
    $service_chcecked = $_POST['service_chcecked'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity_chcecked'];
    $net_price = $_POST['net_price_chcecked'];
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($service_chcecked); ++$x) {
        echo '<tr><td>id:' . $x . '</td><td>name:' . $service_chcecked[$x] . '</td>';
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($net_price); ++$y) {
            echo '<td>price:' . $net_price[$y] . '</td>';
            for ($z = 0; $z < count($quantity); ++$z) {
                echo '<td>quantity:' . $quantity[$z] . '</td>';
            };
        };
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

And my html place:

```
  <div class='services'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><span>NO.</span></th>
      <th><span>Service name</span></th>
      <th><span>Net price</span></th>
      <th><span>Quantity</span></th>
    </tr>
        <?php listServiceName(); ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now it displays to me this way, with repeated data at the end :/
[broken table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7QJO.png)

Comment: `function listService()` yet you're using `listServiceName()` after. Something doesn't add up for me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are nesting your for loops. You create the `<tr>` and the "id" and "name" `<td>` for each item in `service_chcecked`. Then you create a "price" `<td>` for each `service_chcecked` * `net_price_chcecked`. And your 3rd nested loop creates a "quantity" column for each `service_chcecked` * `net_price_chcecked` * `quantity_chcecked`. That's why you end up with that broken table. It depends on how you receive the POST data, but if your three arrays always have the same length, you could do it all in one loop:

```
function listService()
{
    $service_chcecked = $_POST['service_chcecked'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity_chcecked'];
    $net_price = $_POST['net_price_chcecked'];
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($service_chcecked); ++$x) {
        echo '<tr><td>id:' . $x . '</td><td>name:' . $service_chcecked[$x] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>price:' . $net_price[$x] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>quantity:' . $quantity[$x] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand whats happening but less is more and try not to mix your data & html inside your function its going to confuse you later on.

```
  <?php 
      $services = $_POST['service_checked'];
      $qtys = $_POST['quantity_checked'];
      $prices = $_POST['net_price_checked'];
  ?>
  <div class='services'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>NO.</th>
      <th>Service name</th>
      <th>Net price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <? foreach($services as $k=>$service){?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$k?></td>
      <td><?=$service?></td>
      <td><?=$qtys[$k]?></td>
      <td><?=$prices[$k]?></td>
    </tr>
    <? }?>
    </table>
</div>
```